# My login form is redirecting to another form although it has empty inputs. How should I prevent this to happenning?

Tags: vb.net

I was testing my login form and when I double checked that my login button is redirecting although the textboxes are empty.

I'm trying to figure this out tonight but I'm a beginner in it, actually a student. So, please help me to understand what's wrong with my codes. This program is for my activity as well, thanks!

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports System.Reflection.Metadata
Imports System.Windows
Imports System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles.VisualStyleElement
Imports System.Xml

Public Class Form1

    Dim con As New OleDbConnection
    Dim dbProvider As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;"
    Dim dbSource As String = "Data Source=C:\Users\Kuraku\source\repos\Program\Database1.accdb;"

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        con.ConnectionString = dbProvider & dbSource
        Me.CenterToScreen()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        If TextBox1.Text = Nothing Or TextBox2.Text = Nothing Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter your correct credentials", "Error",
            MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        End If

        If con.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
            con.Open()
        End If

        Using login As New OleDbCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table1 WHERE 
        [USERNAME] = @USERNAME AND [PASSWORD] = @PASSWORD", con)
            login.Parameters.AddWithValue("@USERNAME", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text.Trim
            login.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PASSWORD", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox2.Text.Trim

            Dim logincount = Convert.ToInt32(login.ExecuteScalar())
            If logincount > 0 Then
                Form4.Show()


            Else
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter your correct credentials", "Error",
                MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
                TextBox1.Clear()
                TextBox2.Clear()
            End If

        End Using

        con.Close()

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

        Dim redirect = True

        If redirect Then
            Me.Hide()
            Form2.Show()
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: This is a good opportunity for you to start familiarizing yourself with [using a debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/328193).  When you step through the code in a debugger, which operation first produces an unexpected result?  What were the values used in that operation?  What was the result?  What result was expected?  Why?  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: In VB, you should use AndAlso and OrElse by default and only use And and Or if you specifically want to avoid short-circuiting, which should be rare to never. I suggest that you read up on the difference.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a Return statement in that first If block, so execution will end there if you find an empty control.

Comment: Thank you! I did not know that some syntax in Java and C can also be used here. Thanks!